# Disable "Start In" validation in shortcut

Tags: shortcut

Like a good boy, I like to modify my group policies from a non-server machine.

The problem I'm facing almost daily now is that I'm modifying a bunch of shortcuts from my local machine that points to software that I don't have installed. So, I'm seeing this message constantly:

[image: The folder specified in the Start In box is not valid. Make sure that the folder exists and that the path is correct.]

So, my only option is to either log on to a server that *does* have the path, or to create that folder before clicking OK (which is a pain because there's heaps of different Start In paths).

Is there any way to disable this "Start In" validation?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any way to disable that property, but it looks like you can batch-change all of your shortcut files with a PowerShell script. I'm not a PoSH expert by any means, but it looks like "Start in" is the working directory property:

- [Powershell Script to mass-change shortcut files](http://www.squiggle.org/2010/02/powershell-script-to-mass-change-shortcut-path/)
- [Another simple PoSH example](http://scriptzilla.blogspot.com/2009/07/powershell-update-desktop-shortcut.html)
- [MS docs describing working directory property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsy6k3ys.aspx)
- [Another useful discussion about changing `.lnk` files](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/zh/ITCG/thread/545c0b6a-e8ec-42a1-85f5-b6c59b83e1e9)